# Lazy loading router very slow in vue3

Tags: vue.js, router

I tried to use this technique: `const Foo = () => import ('./ Foo.vue');`
for my routers, but strangely when I bring my application to the server it takes a long time to open the SPA page.

If I use `import Test from('./ Foo.vue');` everything is much faster. Why is that?

---

P.S.: I use `vite` + `vue 3`

Comment: It's unknown why this happens in your case. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask and https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve . You can check in devtools which requests are the longest, and why, but currently only you can do that

Answer (score 2):

Maybe the problem appears because you are trying to lazy load a component using the Vue 2.x syntax, using dynamic `import()`

In the Vue 3.x you need to wrap the component, which you want to lazy load, in a new `defineAsyncComponent` function:

```js
import { defineAsyncComponent } from 'vue'

const asyncModal = defineAsyncComponent(() => import('./Modal.vue'))
```

Here is the section about this in [Vue 3 migration guide](https://v3-migration.vuejs.org/breaking-changes/async-components.html#_3-x-syntax)

Comment: i tested your code, but the problem remain. :(